# TeXStudio : Disable auto-completion of parentheses

Tags: punctuation, texstudio, auto-completion

I cannot stand the auto-completion of TeXStudio (formerly TexMakerX) regarding parentheses, braces, etc. I agree auto-completion is useful sometimes, but here it does just not work as I would like. How can I remove it completely?

Under `configuration -> completion` nothing is checked. From where do I remove the auto-completion of these?

Comment: There are parentheses `()`, braces `{}`, and brackets `[]`. I don’t get any sort of auto-completion for parentheses in Texmaker. Could you describe in how exactly we can reproduce the undesired behavior you’re asking about? A screen shot might be helpful as well.

Comment: Have you seen “Auto Complete Parentheses” under “Special Options” in the “Adv. Editor” tab of the “Configure TeXstudio” window?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Great that is it, thank you ! Can you post this as an answer so I accept it ? I actually haven't seen the Advance editor box, which opens up some good customization options. Love it. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, so we’re talking about Texstudio/TexMakerX? Could you edit your question accordingly?

Comment: @doncherry: Just did it. Sorry, forgot this isn't the original TexMaker. I will actually have a look to see their differences. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Under *Options* → *Configure TeXstudio* → *Adv. Editor* → *Special options* the option *Auto Complete Parentheses* dis-/enables the Auto-Completion of all braces, brackets and parentheses.
The Tab *Adv. Editor* is visible after the checkbox *Show Advanced Options* is checked.

[image]

Comment: +1 for Screenshot: I am always confused by GUI configurations.

Comment: Wow, Tex Studio has made it very hard to figure out how to turn off their annoying autocomplete feature.

Comment: Yes. How is this considered an advanced feature? It's nearly impossible to write out maths with it enabled.

Comment: After unchecking that box, for some reason I can't use special characters such as "~" from keyboard anymore. When I type "ALT + 126" I don't get anything. Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Just to make it extra clear since it took me a second: You have to check the box Show-Advanced Options for Adv. Editor to appear.