# How to disable automatic highlighting of TeXStudio for matched LaTeX tokens?

Tags: texstudio

This question is different that the following question

[TeXStudio : Disable auto-completion of parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99616/texstudio-disable-auto-completion-of-parentheses)

The above question asks how to disable automatic completion of parentheses (which I have disabled).

I am not able to find how to disable another very annoying feature. When the mouse is on a "(" or a "$" or "{" any token that requires a corresponding token on the other side, TexStudio jumps in and highlights these with a yellow box and changes the letter to red.

I spend long time and googling and not able to find what I need to turn off. I think I turned off almost everything, and it still does it. Turned of all syntax highlighting I can see.

Here is an example:

[image]

Here is my configuration

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am ready to uninstall this software, but thought to ask here first. (or may be I should just use emacs and be done with it)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Windows 7, 64 bit. Miktex 9 (latest)

thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only help with one part: Use Emacs (with AUCTeX) and be done with it. ;)

Comment: In the syntax highlighting window right click on the colors for bracematch to remove them. I would ask such questions at the sourceforge site of texstudio. They are quite helpful there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks!  I had no idea one has to also "right" click on the colors to also turn that off. I assumed that what the checkbox was for, which I did turn off. Please make this an answer to close this. I did not know about  the sourceforge site of texstudio. Thanks again. I have now decided to delay my switch to emacs.

Comment: @Nasser: Well I didn't know it either. But it was quite obvious for me that the colors could be changed and that they must be a way to disable a color -- after all some of the color blobs didn't show a color. So I right click to see if there is a context menu.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well, what can I say. You are then just smarter than me :) as I did not think of clicking on the color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the syntax highlighting window right click on the colors for bracematch to remove them. I would ask such questions at the sourceforge site of texstudio. They are quite helpful there.