# Auto parentheses get squared in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

[image]

I have just installed TexStudio and when I start typing "(" the ")" appears but it's also squared. If I delete it and type it manually everything's fine. TexStudio's version is 2.12.6 so I don't have any advanced editor here.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: @Bobyandbob hi, I figured out that I can just continue typing my way and the squared ")" will replace with a normal one but I wonder is there any way to disable this auto parentheses function?

Comment: TeXStudio : Disable auto-completion of parentheses - https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99616/124842

Comment: @Bobyandbob Yup, but I don't think I have any advanced editor there.

Comment: You need to check the 'show advanced options' on the bottom left corner of the 'Configure TeXstudio' dialog, then Advanced Editor tab will appear in the options.

Comment: @Troy thank you very much, I did not see this button, it was hided behind my display line lol...

Comment: No problem, in that case I'll vote to close as duplicate as the linked question.