# How to remove the explanation comment in TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio

I have been used TeXstudio since a few days ago.

When I wrote some math commands, the explanation sometimes appeared.

It blinds my writing, and I feel really uncomfortable.

If possible, please let me know the way to remove the explanation part.

[image: figure]

---

Thank you for your comments. As someone said, I unchecked Show help as tooltip on text in editor.

[image: unchecked]

However, I continually got the pop-up as follows.

[image: pop-up]

If you can solve my problem, please let me know the way.

Comment: Did you have a look in here: [TeXStudio : Disable auto-completion of parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99616/texstudio-disable-auto-completion-of-parentheses)

Comment: @MajidAbdolshah Thank you for your suggestion. However, I want to make TeXstudio not to pop up the explanation such as "16.2. Math symbols, ..." in my figure. Can you help me?

Comment: You probably want Options -> Configure TeXstudio (check Show advanced options) -> Adv. Editor -> uncheck Show help as tooltip on text in editor.

Comment: They seem to be TeXdoc previews and one or two settings may be related unfortunately my TeXstudio is running on a MiKTeX that's not feeling well at present and wont show TeXdoc outputs so cant test that hypothesis for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Help as Tooltips is controlled via Configure > Advanced Options > Advanced Editor

[image]

also in Completion settings (Kudos to Red-Cloud for this pointer and linked image)
at [How to Disable Text-Help Pop-Ups in TeXstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490845/how-to-disable-text-help-pop-ups-in-texstudio)

[image]

Comment: Unchecking these boxes did not eliminate the tooltips for me on the new TeXstudio. The `\frac` tooltip appears every time I start to type `\frac`.