# \left\{ \right\} – TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

Unfortunately, neither google nor stackoverflow wants to search special characters like `\` and `{`, I was not able to find a similar question.

I am wondering why TXS immediately autocomplete `\}` and `\right\}` whenever I type `\{` and `\left\{` respectively. How can I disable such an immediate autopletion?

Comment: Cancel the check box in `TeXstudio Configure -> Adv. Editor ->Auto Complete Parentheses`. You need also check the "Show Advanced Options" box at the lower left corner of Configure window.

Comment: Does the posting [TeXStudio : Disable auto-completion of parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99616/5001) help?