# Unwanted Closing Brace Keeps Appearing with Every \Command{

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

Question: How may I prevent an annoying closing brace from appearing each time I type \begin{
or \ followed by some command{

Incidentally, I am using TeXStudio 2.6.6

I have gone to Options, Configure (TeXStudio), Completion, and verified that NONE of the following boxes are checked: (1) Automatically Start Completion When Typing Latex Commands, (2) Auto Replace Latex Commands, nor any of the other two boxes that appear as well.

I checked out other posts but could not figure out how to correct the problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Probably found under the advanced editor settings under texstudio settings.

Comment: This answer from a different question might be helpful, in case you haven't seen it yet: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99663/217170

Comment: @John Many thanks! It worked.